# Mongodb's $match returns multiple occurrences of the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have the following document structure:

```
{
name: "some user name",
  cvs: [{
    title: 'Cv title'
    technologies: [
      {
        text: 'JavaScript',
        main: true
      },
      {
        text: "AngularJs",
        main: true
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

When I make the following aggregation (there is only one document in db):

```
db.users.aggregate([

{"$unwind": "$cvs"},
{"$unwind": "$cvs.technologies"},
{"$match": {
    "cvs.isBlocked": false,
    "cvs.moderated": true,
    "cvs.isVisible": true,
    "cvs.technologies.main": true 
    }
 },
  {"$project": {
      "type": "$cvs.occupationType",
      "proficiency": "$cvs.proficiencyLevel",
      "_id": "$cvs._id",
      "title": "$cvs.title",
      "technologies": "$cvs.technologies.text",
     }}
])
```

I get an array of two elements (but this is the same document) just because there are two technologies matching

```
"cvs.technologies.main": true

[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5629e813279b62fe075fbd4c"),
        "type" : "Frontend",
        "proficiency" : "Middle",
        "title" : "Frontend developer",
        "technologies" : "JavaScript",
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5629e813279b62fe075fbd4c"),
        "type" : "Frontend",
        "proficiency" : "Middle",
        "title" : "Frontend developer",
        "technologies" : "Ruby",
    }
]
```

How can I get this result?:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5629e813279b62fe075fbd4c"),
        "type" : "Frontend",
        "proficiency" : "Middle",
        "title" : "Frontend developer",
        "technologies" : ["JavaScript", "Ruby"],
    }
]
```

Comment: Please show sample document with same structure as the documents in your collection. I think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following pipeline which puts additional **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline steps in order to **[optimize](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/)** the aggregation pipeline (placing a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline before the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** to filter out unwanted documents going through the pipeline) get the desired result (using the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator to group the documents by the given fields, use the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator to create an array):

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "cvs.isBlocked": false,
            "cvs.moderated": true,
            "cvs.isVisible": true,
            "cvs.technologies.main": true 
        }
    },
    {"$unwind": "$cvs"},
    {"$unwind": "$cvs.technologies"},
    {
        "$match": {
            "cvs.isBlocked": false,
            "cvs.moderated": true,
            "cvs.isVisible": true,
            "cvs.technologies.main": true 
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "type": "$cvs.occupationType",
                "proficiency": "$cvs.proficiencyLevel",
                "_id": "$cvs._id",
                "title": "$cvs.title"               
            },
            "technologies": {
                "$push": "$cvs.technologies.text"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "type": "$_id.type",
            "proficiency": "$_id.proficiency",
            "_id": "$_id._id",
            "title": "$_id.title",
            "technologies": 1,
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: That does the trick! But 'type' and 'proficiency' are missing in the result. Only title and technologies are there

Comment: @user2814599 Updated answer, typo. Should work now :-)

Comment: I should have checked to find the typo before asking!. It works! Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me please, how I can include data from the 'users' collection itself (that has the above described nested documents) to the $project? E.g. user.name.

Comment: Can you please create a new question for that?

Comment: here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355004/how-to-include-collection-data-on-aggregation