# How to include collection data on aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB document structure:

```
user: {
  name: 'user name',
  email: 'email@gmail.com',
  isBlocked: false,
  cvs: [{
    title: "role title",
    technologies: [
      {name: 'JavaScript'}
      {name: 'NodeJs'}
   ],
    agents: [
     {
      _id:'some id1',
      contactRequest: true
     },
     {
      _id:'some id2',
      contactRequest: false
     }
    ],
  }]
}
```

How can I add `user.name` to the output if I perform an aggregation with grouping on embedded document's property, e.g.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "cvs.isBlocked": false,
            "cvs.moderated": true,
            "cvs.isVisible": true,
            "cvs.technologies.main": true 
        }
    },
    {"$unwind": "$cvs"},
    {"$unwind": "$cvs.technologies"},
    {
        "$match": {
            "cvs.isBlocked": false,
            "cvs.moderated": true,
            "cvs.isVisible": true,
            "cvs.technologies.main": true 
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "type": "$cvs.occupationType",
                "proficiency": "$cvs.proficiencyLevel",
                "_id": "$cvs._id",
                "title": "$cvs.title"               
            },
            "technologies": {
                "$push": "$cvs.technologies.text"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "type": "$_id.type",
            "proficiency": "$_id.proficiency",
            "_id": "$_id._id",
            "title": "$_id.title",
            "technologies": 1,
        }
    }
])
```

$$ROOT refers to $cvs in that case.

Additionally I would like to include `user.name` and `email` only if `user.isBlocked` is `false` and `agent.contactRequest` is `true`.

Comment: But you have multiple `contactRequest` fields inside the `agent` document array which all have different values, how then do you determine which field to use for the criteria `agent.contactRequest: true`?

Comment: I take all cvs, that have given agent._id and include no contact data. However, if an agent has contactRequest=true, than I should also include contact details. E.g. there are 5 cvs with same agent._id. But only for 2 cvs an agent has contactRequest=true. So 2 cvs should contain contact data from user object, and 3 - should NOT.

Comment: add your extra collection field in $project field